# Retrieving slow-to-load HTML from web page via Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, dom-events

I'm trying to extract a list of CSVs from [BitMEX](https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/quote/). The page executes some (rather slow to load) Javascript in order to render the actual index of the directory (why they've chosen to do this is beyond me -- perhaps obfuscation?).

I have the following Python 3.x code which uses the Python language bindings for Selenium:

```py
#!/bin/python3

import datetime
from urllib import request
import sys
from sys import argv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DOM_LOAD_WAIT = 60
COMMENT_CHAR = '#'

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

def get_html(url):
    # configure headlessness for the webdriver
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(DOM_LOAD_WAIT)

    # constantly retry until success
    while True:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit(1)
        except:
            eprint("Retrying \"{}\"...".format(url))
            continue

    return driver

def get_results(url):
    driver = None

    try:
        driver = get_html(url)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, DOM_LOAD_WAIT).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "pre"))
        )
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    print(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://public.bitmex.com/?prefix=data/quote/"
    get_results(url.strip())
    print("", end=None, flush=True) # flush stdout!
```

The issue is that the script retrieves the *initial* page source, rather than the eventual page source I'm after (i.e., after the Javascript has fully executed -- which can take some time):

```
$ ./script.py
<html><head>
  <title>public.bitmex.com</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; connect-src https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com; script-src 'sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7' 'sha384-n0cKBy1+1+ACIC9J2XunFZItQjpIi1bilP1FCayDxybB40OcUY1ipK4Qjr856KWI' 'sha384-Rncjr7coAsbMCINMdkum6h64TPVhqlDpqulDQB/a68yABAgOU21duBLDdlm86oKP'; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; require-sri-for script style; block-all-mixed-content;">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navigation"></div>
  <div id="listing"><img src="//public.bitmex.com/ajaxload-circle.gif"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.bitmex.com/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.bitmex.com/init.js" integrity="sha384-n0cKBy1+1+ACIC9J2XunFZItQjpIi1bilP1FCayDxybB40OcUY1ipK4Qjr856KWI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.bitmex.com/list.js" integrity="sha384-Rncjr7coAsbMCINMdkum6h64TPVhqlDpqulDQB/a68yABAgOU21duBLDdlm86oKP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body></html>
```

Specifically, it only retrieves the GIF of the spinning loading wheel, which is (needless to say) very frustrating!

**How can I get the webdriver to only return control after the Javascript has fully executed?**

Note that, due to inconsistent implementations of Content Security Policy, I have to use the Chromium-based webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the driver driver wait until it finds the text 'Last Modified'.

```
def get_results(url):
    driver = None

    try:
        driver = get_html(url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Last Modified')]")))
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Added your code (which looks clean, by the way), but now it times out with `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` (for a timeout of 60s, for what it's worth).

Comment: Nevermind, works after removing the `implicitly_wait` call and repeating a few times.

Comment: Great! Is it still slow though? From calling driver.get to fetching the source code should take less than 5 seconds.

Comment: A more consistent way to do this is to replace the `.presence_of_element_located()` method with `.visibility_of_element_located()`. Presence just means that the elements exists in the DOM. If you wait for it to be visible, it should better represent when the page is done loading.

Comment: The (lack of) speed isn't an issue for this application, but is there an equivalent to `present_of_element_located` that would grab **all** elements matching that XPATH? I understand this isn't actually possible a priori (how can the webdriver know how many elements there are in advance?) but I'd like to grab **all** of the links rendered in the directory index.